# Prop and bool in Coq

Tags: boolean, coq

How can I use a comparison of to rational numbers in an if-statement?

```
if 1 = 2 then 1 else 2
```

`1 = 2` is of course `Prop` and not `bool`.

Comment: Possibly Qeq_bool? Could someone point me in the right direction regarding the difference between Qeq and Qeq_bool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't understand how dfan's answer is related to the question...

Of course, `1 = 2` is a `Prop`, it is the statement that 1 is equal to 2. Hopefully you don't have a proof of this statement...

What you want is a function that, given two natural numbers, `1` and `2`, returns `true` if they are equal, and `false` if they aren't.

The library `Coq.Arith.EqNat` gives you such a function, named `beq_nat`.

In fact, you might want something even better, a function that returns a proof of equality or a proof of difference:

```
(* In Coq.Arith.Peano_dec *)
Theorem eq_nat_dec : forall n m, {n = m} + {n <> m}.
                              (* ^ a proof that n = m
                                           ^ or a proof that n <> m *)
```

`if` is overloaded to work with such things, so you can even write:

```
if eq_nat_dec 2 3 then ... else ...
```

Comment: As a complement to @Ptival, you can directly use beq_nat in your function, and use the related lemmas (``SearchAbout beq_nat`` will show them to you) in your proofs, keeping proofs and programs kind of separate. If dependent types do not frighten you, directly using ``eq_nat_dec`` can be faster.

Comment: My answer was related to the question in that he asked how to compare two rationals in an if statement, and I showed how to do so. His example was naturals but he asked for rationals, so that's the example I gave.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the syntax used here? What does `+` mean in this context, and `{ }`?

Comment: Hm, OK, I found the `sumbool` documentation.

Answer (score 2):

`Qeq_bool` indeed takes two rationals and produces a bool.

```
Require Export QArith_base.
Eval compute in Qeq_bool (3#2) (3#2).                       = true: bool
Eval compute in Qeq_bool (3#2) (5#2).                       = false: bool
Eval compute in (if Qeq_bool (3#2) (5#2) then 7 else 9).    = 9: nat
```